# Tensorflow environment setup in PyCharm IDE

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

We can setup Tensorflow environment in local machine using following options:

- Virtualenv
- "native" pip
- Docker
- Anaconda

For using an IDE like PyCharm is recommended by most of all. Is there any proper guideline to setup Tensorflow in PyCharm IDE using any of above environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have done Tensorflow setup in PyCharm IDE using anaconda environment. Here is the step by step details:

1. First install python in your local machine. I used [Anaconda3](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) environment to install Python.
2. Then install [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda) within the anaconda environment
3. Download and install PyCharm IDE from [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) link.
4. Open PyCharm IDE and then create a simple test project
5. Now go to `File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter` (Under the Project: Test)
6. Select path form project interpreter and set the path below for tensorflow environment `home/user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/python`
   [image]

Then apply and OK.

You can now test and work with tensorflow code as well as python code.